# How to parse date string into integer variables?

Tags: java, string, date

I have a `String` which is formatted like so: `"dd-MM-yyyy"`. I am trying to get the `dd` part of the string saved into a integer `day` variable. I want to do the same for the `MM` and `yyyy` parts of the `String`. I can imagine parsing the `String` using a for loop to separate the `String` whenever the `"/" char` is at the current index in the `for` loop.

How do I split the `String` containing the date into day, month and year respectively, into integer variables for me to operate on? Perhaps transferring this `String` to a `Date` object would make it easier due to a member method or field that handles this (just a thought).

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate of that one, maybe a different question though.

Comment: Duplicate: [Java: Get month Integer from Date](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7182996/642706) and [I want to get Year,Month, Day etc from Java Date…](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9474121/642706) and [java date issue in getting month and year](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13602552/642706) and more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
        String date = "13-08-2016";
        String[] values = date.split("-");
        int day = Integer.parseInt(values[0]);
        int month = Integer.parseInt(values[1]);
        int year = Integer.parseInt(values[2]);
```

You can use `String.split(String regex)` method to parse the date to array of `String` then convert each value to int.

JavaDoc:

> public String[] split(String regex) Splits this string around matches
>   of the given regular expression. This method works as if by invoking
>   the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit
>   argument of zero. Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in
>   the resulting array.

Read more here: [String.split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 3):

Well please specify the language you are using ..

Basically every language provide functions to parse String to Date and then get day, month and year.

In JS,

```
var d = new Date("dd-MM-yyyy")
d.getDay();
d.getMonth();
d.getYear();
```

Similarly in Java,

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy");
Date startDate = df.parse(startDate);
```

Comment: The question has a Java tag. Please edit your answer appropriately

Comment: @cricket_007 already edited.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find the `String.split(String regex)` method useful for your case.

So in your case you could take the string split it and use the split parts:

```
String str = "20-04-2016";
String[] splitArray = str.split("-");
int day = Integer.parseInt(splitArray[0]);
int month = Integer.parseInt(splitArray[1]);
int year = Integer.parseInt(splitArray[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
    String dateStr = "14-08-2016"; 
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"); 
    Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(dateStr);
    System.out.println(date.getMonth()+1);
```

With Java 8

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
    LocalDate parsedDate = LocalDate.parse(dateStr, formatter1);
    System.out.println(parsedDate.getMonth().getValue());
```